# How to make a global menu hover above all screens, like Path does

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit

I need to implement something like the Path menu, which is globally available within the app no matter which screen user stays.

[image]

**Please note** I'm not asking how to implement the animation/styling things, I'm just curious about the proper way to layout the menu cross view controllers.

The approach I'm currently taking is:

1. Create a container view controller, make it as the
   rootViewController of the app
2. Add functional view controllers as child controllers to the root one
3. Create global menu as a view, insert it as a subview to root view
   controller's view, make it appear above other subviews
4. when user select a menu item in the global menu, I need to bring the
   corresponding functional view controller's view to the front, but
   still underneath global menu view

The downside of this approach is:

1. Presenting modal view controller will block the global menu
2. Have to pre-load every functional view controllers upfront

In short, I managed to achieve the UI/UX expectation, but technically, I feel I'm doing it wrong. Has anyone got similar project experience, please share your thoughts.

Comment: I am investigating the same question, from the solutions you tried could you detail your final choice and/or the problems you had? The solution you detail in your question seems OK to me... a bit like a tabbarcontroller except it only handles a menu.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions,

1. You could add your a global menu into AppDelegate,

   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOption

Then you could add your global menu into navigation controller view, such as,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.viewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.navigationController.delegate = self.viewController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

    // Your Global Menu
    UIButton *myButton ...
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:myButton];  

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

1. You could create a BaseViewController, and add your global buttons into BaseViewController. Then all other viewcontrollers inherit BaseViewController. So some view controller could have global menu. If some view controllers don't want global menu, just inherit the normal UIViewController.

Such as,

```
#import "GlobalMenuView.h"

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIButton *btnMenu;
    GlobalMenuView *globalMenu;
}

@end
```

Then the view controller which wants global menu just do,

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface YourOtherViewController: BaseViewController
{

}

@end
```

Comment: please give me some time to try this solution

Comment: regarding the second solution, when you perform a view controller transition (push or modal), you fill see the view controller being transited in has the global menu button as well

Answer (score 1):

You could probably add it straight onto the UIWindow after making sure the the main UIViewController has already been added?

Comment: I worked on an app that used this technique. You can indeed add subviews directly to the UIWindow, and they will hover above any other content. You may need to manually listen for orientation change events and reposition your `UIView` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably not any help now, but there is also a better solution to what you want to achieve. What you could do is subclass a UIView object, and then in your app delegate class, in your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method, you can insert the following code

```
[self.window insertSubview:(UIView) aboveSubview:(UIView)];
```

and that should give you the thing you want to accomplish :)

Hope that helps any